# '>' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict' in Django 3.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I am using Django 3.0 and Python 3.7

here is my views.py

```
@login_required
def updated_status(request, pk):
    s1 = []
    purchase_quantity = Item.objects.filter(order_id=pk)
    data = set()
    a = [x.id for x in purchase_quantity if x.id not in data and not data.add(x.id)]
    stock_quantity = Stock.objects.filter(other_id=pk)
    data1 = set()
    b = [x.other_item.id for x in stock_quantity if
         x.other_item.id not in data1 and not data1.add(x.other_item.id)]
    if data == data1:
        for j in data1:
            stock_quantity = Stock.objects.filter(other_order_id=pk,
                                                           other_item_id=j).aggregate(Sum('quantity'))
            purchase_quantity = Item.objects.filter(
                    other_id=pk, id=j).aggregate(Sum('quantity'))
            if stock_quantity > purchase_quantity:
                Order.objects.filter(id=pk).update(flag=1)
            if stock_quantity >= purchase_quantity:
                s1.append('true')
            else:
                s1.append('false')
            if 'false' in s1:
                Order.objects.filter(id=pk).update(status=3)
            else:
                Order.objects.filter(id=pk).update(status=2)
    else:
        pass
    return redirect(reverse('get_list_data'))
```

How could i solve this issue " TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict' "

Answer (score 0):

Both `stock_quantity` and `purchase_quantity` are dictionaries here: you need to unwrap the item from the dictionary, so:

```
stock_quantity = StockMovements.objects.filter(
    other_order_id=pk, other_order_item_id=j
).aggregate(Sum('quantity'))['quantity__sum']
purchase_item_quantity = OtherOrderItem.objects.filter(
    other_order_id=pk, id=j
).aggregate(Sum('quantity'))['quantity__sum']
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

Django aggregate return dict object.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/

```
for j in data1:
    stock_quantity = StockMovements.objects.filter(other_order_id=pk, other_order_item_id=j).aggregate(Sum('quantity'))
    purchase_item_quantity = OtherOrderItem.objects.filter(other_order_id=pk, id=j).aggregate(Sum('quantity'))
    if stock_quantity.get('quantity__sum') > purchase_item_quantity.get('quantity__sum'):
        OtherOrder.objects.filter(id=pk).update(flag=1)
    if stock_quantity.get('quantity__sum') >= purchase_item_quantity.get('quantity__sum'):
        pass
```

> aggregate() is a terminal clause for a QuerySet that, when invoked,
> returns a dictionary of name-value pairs. The name is an identifier
> for the aggregate value; the value is the computed aggregate. The name
> is automatically generated from the name of the field and the
> aggregate function. If you want to manually specify a name for the
> aggregate value, you can do so by providing that name when you specify
> the aggregate clause: